# How can I pass multiple values to template using Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently use it like this:

```
function getNewPageContent(clientType, clientName, clientId) {
  if (clientType === "AP") {
    const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ap_dashboard');
    template.clientName = clientType;
    return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();
  }
}
```

and I get it on the page nicely like this:

```
<script>  
  let clientName = <?= clientName ?>;
</script>
```

What if I need to pass `clientName`, `clientType` and `clientId`?

Should I use `JSON.stringify()` like so? (...which hasn't worked by the way)

```
function getNewPageContent(clientType, clientName, clientId) {
  if (clientType === "AP") {
    const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ap_dashboard');
    template.clientInfo = JSON.stringify({
      clientType: clientType,
      clientName: clientName,
      clientId: clientId
    });
    return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();
  }
}
```

...and then get it like this on the other side:

```
<script>  
const clientInfo = JSON.parse(<?= clientInfo ?>);
console.log(clientInfo);
const clientType = clientInfo.clientType; 
const clientId = clientInfo.clientId;
const clientName = clientInfo.clientName;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have found that you can just pass in a global obj as shown below:

There is no need to stringify and then parse

gs:

```
function myFunck1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  return vs;
}

function launchAsASimpleDialog() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah1");
  t.obj = {heading1: "This is heading one",heading2:"This is heading two", id:"tabledata"};
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),"Simple Dialog");
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h1><?= obj.heading1 ?></h1>
    <div id="<?= obj.id ?>">
       <? var vs = myFunck1(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
   <h1><?= obj.heading2 ?></h1>  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it. Not officially documented, right? Thanks a lot