# Passing Variable from Apps Script code.gs to HTML template

Tags: variables, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an HTMl email when a student is changed to "pending". I am to the point that I can send the email with the HTML template with the variables NOT replaced followed by the htmlBody in the script with the variables replaced. How do I get the variables to be replaced in the html template? I'm new and know just enough to be dangerous.

code.gs is

```
function onPendingEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  //Event Variables
  var range = e.range;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  var parentEmail = sheet.getRange(row,30).getValue();
  var studentEmail = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue();
  var studentFirstName = sheet.getRange(row,9).getValue();
  var studentLastName = sheet.getRange(row,10).getValue();
  var team1 =  sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  var team2 =  sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
  var team3 =  sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue();
  
  var recipient = studentEmail + (',') + parentEmail;

  // get HTML template file
  //var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pendingEmail');
  var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('pendingEmail').getContent();

  // set the values for the placeholders
  template.parentEmail = sheet.getRange(row,30).getValue();
  template.studentEmail = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue();
  template.studentFirstName = studentFirstName;
  template.studentLastName = studentLastName;

  if ( col == 2 && cellValue == "Pending"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: "Your application is pending. Next Steps.",
//    body: "Changed to Pending." + parentEmail + studentEmail + studentFirstName + studentLastName + team1 + team2 + team3,
   htmlBody: template + "<P>Your application is pending! Hello " + studentFirstName + studentLastName + "Congrats! Your application is pending! Welcome aboard, " + studentFirstName + ". You have been added to team " + team1 + " " + team2 + " " + team3 + " " + "pending the following steps: 1. Register with FIRST and accept the 2024 FIRST Consent and Release Form. Detailed instructions can be found here. https://www.firstinspires.org/resource-library/youth-registration-system 2. Waiver for FIRST in TX 3. Review our Saftey Manual 4. Sign our Shop Rules. 5. Have your parent contact Charlie to pay dues or agree to a payment plan.",
  });
      Browser.msgBox('An email has been sent to: ' + recipient);
  };
}
```

Results in this email. First half is proper HTML and no variables. Second half variables and no HTMl.

Your application is pending!

Hello

Congrats! Your application is pending!

Welcome aboard, .

You have been added to team    pending the following steps:

1. Register with FIRST and accept the 2024 FIRST Consent and Release Form. Detailed instructions can be found here. https://www.firstinspires.org/resource-library/youth-registration-system
2. Waiver for FIRST in TX
3. Review our Saftey Manual
4. Sign our Shop Rules.
5. Have your parent contact Charlie to pay dues or agree to a payment plan.

Your application is pending! Hello JaneDoeCongrats! Your application is pending! Welcome aboard, Jane. You have been added to team 6369 pending the following steps: 1. Register with FIRST and accept the 2024 FIRST Consent and Release Form. Detailed instructions can be found here. https://www.firstinspires.org/resource-library/youth-registration-system 2. Waiver for FIRST in TX 3. Review our Saftey Manual 4. Sign our Shop Rules. 5. Have your parent contact Charlie to pay dues or agree to a payment plan.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77413618/7215091)

Comment: [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)